# Detect when two keys are pressed at the same time

Tags: animation, jumping

I'm doing a game with XNA and I need an animation when two keys are pressed.. I tried this but it doesn't function.

```
if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.D) && Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.W))
{
    jumpRight(gameTime);
    vel.X = +2;
}
```

The jump functions and the others animations with only one key pressed function too, but this one doesn't work. What should I do?

Comment: The code seems alright, care to update your post with a little bit more code? I'm particularly interested in your single-key animations as you say those work as expected.

Comment: if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.D))
            {
                animazioneDestra(gameTime);
                velocita.X = 3.5f;
            }

Comment: If, for testing purporses, you change that line to: `if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.D) && Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.W)) { animazioneDestra(gameTime); velocita.X = 3.5f; }`, does it still work when you press both W and D?

Comment: yes it does....

Comment: Post your entire key handling code in your question.  It could potentially be the way you setup your logic.

Comment: I answered your question in my answer below, look for the EDIT.

Comment: Don't forget to accept an answer in case it helped you, or to ask for more information through comments.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend using `Console.WriteLine("some text")` in the future to determine whether or not your code gets reached, in this case:

```
if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.D) && Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.W)) 
{
    Console.WriteLine("D and W pressed!");

    jumpRight(gameTime); 
    vel.X = +2;
}
```

If the message is printed, it could be an error in your `jumpRight`-method.

If the message is NOT printed, it could be an error in the way you setup your logic.

Alternatively, you could learn how to debug your code, for that, refer to this neat little tutorial: http://www.dotnetperls.com/debugging

EDIT:

To answer your question in this particular case, instead of `else if` in say `else if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.A))` use just `if`.

Why? Because when you press A, it does what it has to do when you press A, and then skips over the rest of the if-statement blocks. If you use `if` instead, it won't.

Your new Update-method would look like this (I also removed my earlier suggested code):

```
public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    NS = VS;
    rect = new Rectangle(frameCor * largFrame, 0, largFrame, altFrame);
    origine = new Vector2(rect.Width / 2, rect.Height / 2);
    posizione = posizione + velocita;

    velocita = Vector2.Zero;

    if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.D))
    {
        animazioneDestra(gameTime);
        velocita.X = 3.5f;
    }

    if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.A))
    {
        animazioneSinistra(gameTime);
        velocita.X = -3.5f;
    }

    if (NS.IsKeyDown(Keys.D) && VS.IsKeyDown(Keys.W))
    {
        SaltoDX(gameTime);
        velocita.X = +3;
    }

    if (Keyboard.GetState().GetPressedKeys().Length == 0)
    {
        Stato(gameTime);
        velocita.X = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please note that although you said that you wanted to check if `D` and `W` keys were pressed simultanously, you don't. What you do is, you check if the D key is down. Next, you check if the W key is down. Nothing in your code makes sure that **both** are down at the very same time. Any time you call `GetState` you query the keyboard for it's state. In your code, you check two different keyboard states. If you want to check if both keys are down *in the same instant of time* you need to check it on the *same* keyboard state.

```
// get the state once
var state = Keyboard.GetState();

// check if D and W are down in the same state
if (state.IsKeyDown(Keys.D) && state.IsKeyDown(Keys.W))
{
    // code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your NS and VS KeyboardState objects are never used.  Because of this, you are never checking against your current KeyboardState.

You will need to do something like:

```
VS = Keyboard.GetState()
```